# How to write RFC services in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, saprfc, netweaver

I want to write RFC services in java, so that I can receive call from SAP.

How I can start writing java application?

What kind of java project I have to create?

Comment: As it stands your question is far too broad and vague for Stack Overflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the [SAP Java Connector](https://support.sap.com/jco) (JCo) SDK is most likely what you are looking for.